# PHP создает директории с непонятными правами d-wxr----t

Tags: php, linux

Так создаются директории:

```php
    private function createFolder($folder){
        if (!file_exists($folder)) {
            umask(022);
            if (!mkdir($folder, 0777, TRUE)) {
               $data['state'] = "Server error, do not create content folder";
               jsonExit($data);
            }  
        }
    }
```

$folder содержит к примеру такую строку - "8956/xxhdpi/"
В итогу папка 8956 будет иметь полные права, а вот xxhdpi получает права вида "d-wxr----t"

Как с этим бороться?
p.s. я пробовал добавить umask 022 в envvars апача, но не помогло. Как такое возможно, что php создает каталоги и потом сам не может в них постучаться?

Comment: хм. не удалось воспроизвести вашу ситуацию. 
пытался на debian7 с дефолтными настройками apache2 и php5.4.

Пробовал разные комбинации прав на каталог, где создаются папки, на скрипт их создающий, на сам бинарник апача - везде результат  один - папки создаются с теми правами, которые прошу. может быть, что у вас какая-то нестандартная сборка php или apache ?

Comment: Стандартное все ставил

Comment: @boris_U Как сделать, чтобы создавалось все по умолчанию (и папки и файлы) с полными правами "777"? Хотя бы на время теста так сделать, не могу разобраться

Comment: у родительского (по отношению к создаваемому) каталога какие именно права и атрибуты? добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос вывод двух команд: `ls -ld /путь/к/родительскому/каталогу` и `lsattr -d /путь/к/родительскому/каталогу`

Answer (score 1):

Используйте явно `chmod("/path/dir", 0777);`
Пример:

```
<?
function rechmod($root,$fpath, $mode) {
/**
*       Это пример функции.
*       Никаких проверок не делаем, так-как предполагаем, 
*       что у нас есть право создавать каталоги и файлы.
*       И проблем с их созданием - нет.
*/
    $p_ar = preg_split("/\//",$fpath);
    $path = $root;
    foreach ($p_ar as $p) {
        $path .="/".$p;
        echo "chmod for:\t".$path."\n";
        chmod ($path, 0777);
    }
}

$fpath = "t1/t2";
if (mkdir("/tmp/".$fpath,0755, true))
    rechmod ("/tmp/",$fpath, 0777);
 else
    echo "error";
?>
```